Movie about a man who acquires wish-fulfilling perfume
I want to know the title of a movie. I think it's about perfume. A man who has bad luck in life buys a perfume from a woman in red dress. He is told to use perfume carefully. Perfume fulfills his wishes but consumes him physically (his skin falls off, etc). He dies at the end of movie. The woman in the red dress comes to his apartment and takes the perfume. We don't see woman's face, just her skirt and legs. The movie is a horror/ thriller or something like that.
Year: I think it's from the 2000s-2010s.
Language: Almost sure it was English.
Length: About 80-100 minutes. 

Approximate year of release? Country\language? And are you sure it was a movie?

I think its 2000s-2010s . Language almost sure it was english . Yes it was a movie lenght about 80-100 minutes.

This is it! Thanks Walt :-D

This sounds very much like the first segment of five (called 'Smell') in the 2013 anthology horror film Chilling Visions: 5 Senses of Fear from 2013, but a couple of details are a bit off.

Smell (directed by Nick Everhart) follows a depressed man by the name of Seth (Corey Scott Rutledge). He's in a job he doesn't like and his despondence over his recent breakup has caused him to neglect himself. When a mysterious door to door saleslady offers him a cologne that can change everything for him, Seth takes her up on the offer. Her only warning is that he shouldn't use too much of it. Excited when the cologne starts making him more successful at work and love, Seth is soon horrified when the cologne's side effects start to work on him.

The cologne slowly melts his face and body, until he melts away completely. The saleswoman wears a pink skirt, though, and we do see her in the end when she takes back the cologne. Here's the trailer for the Smell segment [Warning: Slightly Gory In The End]:




This is it. Thanks Walt :-D
